# Unable to use WSO2 Identity Server for OIDC.Getting could not handle request /oauth2/authorize exception

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 Identity Server as KM 5.10.0 . I want to configure my web service as service provider and use the oauth/OIDC login provided by wso2 IS. When my web server is redirecting to wso2 for the authentication, I get the below exception.

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve} - Could not handle request: /oauth2/authorize java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.internal.Utils.getAppNameFromRequest(Utils.java:101)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.initCarbonContext(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:80)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I have correctly registered my webserver in wso2 ID server in "Add service provider section". Also generated the client secret and client key in the process. I am using authorization code grant type.

Please let me know why such exception is thrown, how to debug this

Comment: Can u also add the complete URL with query params that were used in the redirection.(Mask any sensitive details)

Comment: Hi Janak,It worked form me when I used Internet explorer instead of chrome. I am getting the access token now from the ID server. With this access token will I be able to access the APIs on the APIM? I tried this but I am not able to access the APIs.

Comment: Usually, it should work with Chrome. As Janak has mentioned above, please add the URL your app use to redirect the user to the IDP. Accessing the APIs might need different factors such as scopes etc. Please create a separate question for that with required details.